# Machine Learning - global minima and convexity in gradient descent

Tags: calculus, machine-learning

In linear regression we use gradient descent to find the global minimum provided that the cost function is a convex.

```
J = x0 + x1*theta1 + x2*theta2
```

But if we want to use multipliers of features as features as well,

```
J = x0 + x1*theta1 + x2*theta2 + x1*x2*theta3 + x1^2 * theta4 + x1^2 * x2^2 * theta5 ....
```

will the new cost function be a convex? If not as for my knowledge we can't guarantee that we get the global minimum. If so what is the solution in such cases (except using neural networks)?

Comment: Quick note: Non convex/non linear optimiziation is a thing people can do (and not a dead end!), it just happens to be worst case terrible but in practice a lot can be tractable or even just approximated within reason.

Comment: yes, But what i'm curious about is, if I want to use multipliers of features as a new feature, can we still use gradient descent to find out the global minimum? Will we end up in a local minima?

Comment: Gradient descent only works if it's convex, this can be easily checked:  
$$u, v\in \mathbb{R}^n, t \in [0,1], J(tu + (1-t)v) \le t J(u) + (1-t) J(v)$$

See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function

Comment: So in your example (I assume $\theta$ are scalars and $x_i$ are teh variables), you wish to verify if $$(tu_0 + (1-t)v_0)+ ( tu_1 + (1-t)v_1) \theta_1+ (t u_2 + (1 - t) v_2) \theta_2 +  ( tu_1 + (1-t)v_1) (t u_2 + (1 - t) v_2 \theta_3 + ... \le $$ $$t (u_0 + u_1 \theta_1 + u_2 \theta_2 + u_1 u_2 \theta_3+ ... ) + (1-t) (v_0 + v_1 \theta_1 + v_2 \theta_2 + v_1 v_2 \theta_3 + ... ) $$

Comment: A very fast probabilistic algorithm for this would be to consider: the difference of the two, that is $J(tu + (1-t)v) - tJ(u) + (1-t)J(v)$ as a function over 2n variables (n for u, n for v) and try to find a point that causes it dip below zero. If it is very hard to find such a point then it is increasingly likely your function is mostly convex (not a guarantee... but a show that gradient descent used naively isn't a terrible idea here)

Comment: Yep, I get that. Thanks for the guidance! Was really confused at this point.

Answer (score 0):

Everything else on this page is quite old so perhaps no one else will see this, but while I was drafting a question SO showed me this question as being related.

Anyway, I want to point out that while it's true that terms of the form $x_1  x_2 \theta_3$ make your new function non-convex in $x$, depending on the required domain, it would be log-log convex.

You may be interested in "disciplined convex programming", which is a set of rules for constructing functions that are assured to be convex. Closely related is "disciplined geometric programming" which constructs functions that are guaranteed to be log-log convex. In these, multiplication of optimization variables is an allowed operation, but terms must be positive, and subtraction is disallowed.

Because the original question was asked with what looks like a code snippet, I'll point out that cvxpy is a python package that supports both disciplined convex programming and disciplined geometric programming, and has good documentation which explains both in greater detail. The relevant portion for log-log convexity is here: https://www.cvxpy.org/tutorial/dgp/index.html